# Why aren't generic functions the same as accessor functions lisp

Tags: oop, lisp, common-lisp, clos, setf

From the things I have read I understand that Accessor functions in CLOS allows for the programmer to get and set variables and it generates a generic function of the name that was give in to the accessor to which you need to define different methods.But I what I want to know is why Don't generic functions work the same way as the accessor functions?

for example

```
 (defclass animal ()
       ((sound
         :initarg :sound
         :initform "no sound"
         :accessor make-sound)))
```

I can just 
define

```
(defmethod (setf make-sound) ((the-animal animal) value)
       (setf (slot-value the-animal 'sound) value))
```

but if i were to take the accessor away and add in

```
(defgeneric (setf make-sound) (the-animal value))
```

then I get an error when after executing the following code.

```
(setf (make-sound dog) "bark")
```

unless I redefine the generic function and method as the following

```
(defgeneric (setf make-sound) (value the-animal))

 (defmethod (setf make-sound) (value (the-animal animal))
   (setf (slot-value the-animal 'sound) value))
```

or execute

```
(setf (make-sound "bark") dog) ;this also works with the accessor
```

My question is why is this happening?Why can't I achieve the same result with generic functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`defmethod`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defmet.htm#defmethod) form creates a *generic function* if there isn't one.

```
CL-USER 7 > (defclass animal ()
              ((sound
                :initarg :sound
                :initform "no sound")))
#<STANDARD-CLASS ANIMAL 40200ED09B>
```

Remember: the new value comes first in a *SETF function*. That's defined by the Common Lisp standard.

```
CL-USER 8 > (defmethod (setf make-sound) (value (the-animal animal))
              (setf (slot-value the-animal 'sound) value))
#<STANDARD-METHOD (SETF MAKE-SOUND) NIL (T ANIMAL) 40200F098B>

CL-USER 9 > (let ((dog (make-instance 'animal)))
              (setf (make-sound dog) "bark")
              dog)
#<ANIMAL 402002187B>

CL-USER 10 > (slot-value * 'sound)
"bark"
```

Seems to work.

In [`defclass`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm#defclass) the `:accessor` slot option defines that it defines a reader method and also a corresponding *setf method* with the correct parameter list: new value first, then the instance of that class.

Comment: But why can't I just put (the-animal animal) first instead of value as in why do I get an error If i define `(defmethod (setf make-sound) ((the-animal animal) value)
       (setf (slot-value the-animal 'sound) value))`?

Comment: @jakHunter: because the Common Lisp standard defines that the new value is always the first parameter in a SETF function. Thus the function gets always called with the arguments in the correct order.

Comment: I think I get it but why does it work when I Include `:accessor`?

Comment: @jakHunter   The `DEFCLASS` slot option `:accessor` defines a `setf` generic function with the correct argument order.